# Plotting frequency versus intensity of three dependent variables

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot frequency spectrum (independent variable) versus Intensity (x,y,z dependent variables).   My input data are in the following format,

```
data={{1,2,3},{{5,6,7},{3,4,5},{5,3,4}}}
```

My code is

```
  xlist = {1,2,3};
  ylists = {{5,6,7},{3,4,5},{5,3,4}};
  ListLinePlot[ylists, PlotLegends -> Range[3],
  DataRange -> MinMax[xlist]]
```

Do you have alternatives in displaying this type of data?

Comment: `ListLinePlot[ylists, PlotLegends -> Range[3], 
 DataRange -> MinMax[xlist], Mesh -> All]` ? `ListPointPlot3D[ylists]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume that each `i` point on x-axies associated with `j` y points, then for your data you can directly get the plot as

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{data[[1]][[i]], data[[2, j]][[i]]}, {j, 3}, {i, 3}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, PlotLegends -> Range[3], 
 DataRange -> MinMax[data[[1]]]]
```

[image]